# axios cannot send cookie with request even with withCredential: true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I already did the setup on server like this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization,  X-PINGOTHER'
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

and the axios on client side (react) is like this

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios('http://127.0.0.1:3001/orders', {
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
})
```

Everything works fine when I test with Postman and type directly to chrome. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you plan on using this mulitple times, then just create an axios config:

**client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
  ? "http://localhost:3001/"
  : "http://example.com"

const app = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true
})

/* 
  The below is required if you want your API to return 
  server message errors. Otherwise, you'll just get 
  generic status errors.

  If you use the interceptor below, then make sure you 
  return an "err" (or whatever you decide to name it) message 
  from your express route: 
  
  res.status(404).json({ err: "You are not authorized to do that." })

*/
app.interceptors.response.use(
  response => (response), 
  error => (Promise.reject(error.response.data.err))
)

export default app;
```

**client/src/actions/exampleAction.js**

```
import app from '../utils/axiosConfig';

export const exampleAction = () => (
  app.get('orders') // this will be defined as baseURL + "orders" (http://localhost:3001/orders)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
)
```

Then for your API, instead of specifying CORS headers, you can simply use [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) wherever you're defining your `express` middleware:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const origin = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
  ? "http://localhost:3000" 
  : "http://example.com"

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 17):

Now 2020, Chrome add more annoying restricts to cross domain cookies settings, you must set cookies with `SameSite` to `none`, otherwise Chrome will refuse to send cookies. More, if you set SameSite, you must set `secure`.

Below is an example for how to set this change in nginx, it may not work with your situation, but for reference.

```
proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; SameSite=none";
```

Comment: More, if you set SameSite, you must set secure. Thanks man.

Comment: is there a way to allow this without secure?  (ie: if my localhost dev system is just http) ?

Comment: thank you for your note, that was really important for my case

Answer (score 6):

I figure out my mistake. Change axios code to

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios('http://localhost:3001/orders', {
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true
}).then(res => {
     console.log(res);
   }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response);
   })
```

I still want to ask why does this change help so any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

same issue and I fixed it. Follow code:

**Backend**

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options('*', cors(corsConfig))
```

**frontend**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I was making a put request with axios.

```
axios.put(‘URL’, {withCredentials: true})
```

I reconstructed my request too and it worked. Meanwhile, remember to also set your cors config to have the “credentials: true”.

```
axios(‘URL’, {
  method: ‘PUT‘,
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login',{ userEmail, userPassword },{
        withCredentials: true,
      })


const cors = require("cors");
expressApplication.use(cors({
 origin: ["http://localhost:2000", "http://localhost:3000"],
 credentials: true
}));
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some description of what it does? Some of the code is for the front end and the rest for the back end, right?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just adding an empty `{}` as I was using `axios.post` -> the first `{}` in the `.post` arguments is `data` argument

From :

```
const response = await axios.post(
        "/users/logout",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
```

To :

```
const response = await axios.post(
        "/users/logout",
        {},
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use axios in main or preload, to use cookie session need execute from index.js load in browserwindow, config websecurity to true,
maybe you can read this article

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-rest-api-calls-in-electronjs/

Answer (score -2):

I found this article helpful: https://medium.com/acmvit/handling-cookies-with-axios-872790241a9b

But might depend on the server setup.

In client set Axios headers:

```
headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${cookie_value}`},
withCredentials: true,
crossDomain: true
```